# Why does my appended object start to distort when I move it?

Tags: objects, append, object-mode

I'm appending a tree into another scene. After I try moving it to set up my scene, the branches start to distort. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

http://g.recordit.co/rJuzSYSsHw.gif

Comment: Does your tree have any armatures or rigging?

Comment: Check their transformation (rotation/scale) and apply them if needed with Ctrl+A

Comment: yes, there was rigging applied. Problem solved after removing the rigging. Thanks!